# What is the max linear acceleration of Husky A200?

Tags: ros, pid, gazebo, ros-melodic, husky

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I am not experienced in doing robotics. I have been trying to find the max linear acceleration of Husky A200 in order to set real constraint for simulation purposes.

What I did was to find out the drive power of the Husky A200 (https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwicqdH7ravlAhX-6nMBHV3oCQ4QFjADegQIBhAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gaitech.hk%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2014%2F07%2FHusky-Product-Overview.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0iPYaBKHOHYlbG5CQyj00E).

Drive Power = 400 W continuous (4 wheels), thus Drive Power = 100 W continuous (1 wheel).

Using

> Acceleration = Power/(Mass x Velocity), where max velocity = 1 m/s (also in the link above) and Mass = 57.69 kg

I got

> Max Acceleration = 1.733 m/s^2

Is the calculation correct? If yes, what does it mean when Max Acceleration > Max Velocity in magnitude? Does it just mean that the velocity will just be capped at 1 m/s even if the velocity can be increased by 1.733 m/s in a second?

Thanks for viewing.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335763/what-is-the-max-linear-acceleration-of-husky-a200?/) by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2019-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [husky_control/config/control.yaml](https://github.com/husky/husky/blob/677120693643ca4b6ed3c14078dedbb8ced3b781/husky_control/config/control.yaml#L29-L42) which is shipped by Clearpath themselves, the max linear acceleration is `3.0` m/s^2:

```
  # Velocity and acceleration limits
  # Whenever a min_* is unspecified, default to -max_*
  linear:
    x:
      has_velocity_limits    : true
      max_velocity           : 1.0   # m/s
      has_acceleration_limits: true
      max_acceleration       : 3.0   # m/s^2
  angular:
    z:
      has_velocity_limits    : true
      max_velocity           : 2.0   # rad/s
      has_acceleration_limits: true
      max_acceleration       : 6.0   # rad/s^2
```

This is not necessarily the *real* acceleration limit, but is what they configure the ROS-side controllers with.

Note that this same file is used with the simulated version (by [husky_control/launch/control.launch](https://github.com/husky/husky/blob/677120693643ca4b6ed3c14078dedbb8ced3b781/husky_control/launch/control.launch) from [husky_gazebo/launch/spawn_husky.launch](https://github.com/husky/husky/blob/677120693643ca4b6ed3c14078dedbb8ced3b781/husky_gazebo/launch/spawn_husky.launch). So the official simulation uses the same limits.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-20**:
PS: seeing as you've tagged this with `gazebo`: is there a specific reason you can't use the provided `husky_gazebo` package?

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2019-10-20**:
Thank you very much. Yes, I am using gazebo as part of the simulation but I think I might have missed this one out.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-21**:
Is there any specific reason why you cross-posted this to Robotics Stack Exchange ([here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/19629))?

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2019-10-21**:
I posted on two website just in case one forum is inactive. I have closed the post in Robotics Stack Exchange already. Thanks again!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-21**:\

> I posted on two website just in case one forum is inactive.

In the future: please don't cross-post. It's not very nice, as in the best case, it leads to split discussions, but typically (and that would be the worst case) it leads to duplication (ie: waste) of effort.

Post in one place and give people time to respond to your question.

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2019-10-21**:
Roger that. Thanks for the info.